# Tensorflow Hub in C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

Is it possible to use the TensorFlow Hub in the C++ Api? I would like to transform the following example.

```
# Load content and style images (see example in the attached colab).
content_image = plt.imread(content_image_path)
style_image = plt.imread(style_image_path)
# Convert to float32 numpy array, add batch dimension, and normalize to range [0, 1]. Example using numpy:
content_image = content_image.astype(np.float32)[np.newaxis, ...] / 255.
style_image = style_image.astype(np.float32)[np.newaxis, ...] / 255.
# Optionally resize the images. It is recommended that the style image is about
# 256 pixels (this size was used when training the style transfer network).
# The content image can be any size.
style_image = tf.image.resize(style_image, (256, 256))

# Load image stylization module.
hub_module = hub.load('https://tfhub.dev/google/magenta/arbitrary-image-stylization-v1-256/2')

# Stylize image.
outputs = hub_module(tf.constant(content_image), tf.constant(style_image))
stylized_image = outputs[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

A TensorFlow Hub module is typically not ready to be used for inference. One often needs to append extra ops before or after to adjust to its use case and then create a new SavedModel that could be used in C++.

The suggestion here would be to create a python program that converts the hub module into your use case. I.e. a program that has a tf.function with an input signature that goes from filenames into a generated image, or from 2 input images into a new image and then save that into a new SavedModel for serving in C++.